# Hide characters in email address using an SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I have a very specific business requirement to hide certain characters within an email address when returned from SQL and I have hit the limit of my ability with SQL to achieve this. I was wondering if someone out there would be able to point me in the right direction. Essentially, my business is asking for the following:

`test@email.com` to become `t*\*t@e**l.com`
or

`thislong@emailaddress.com` to become `t******h@e**********s.com`

I am aware that if either portion of the email before of after the @ are less than 3 characters, then this won't work, but I intend on checking for this and dealing with it appropriately. I have tried a mixture of SUBSTRING, STUFF, LEFT/RIGHT etc but I can't quite get it right.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? String functions are quite different between different database products

Comment: I am attempting to do this in MS SQL. I could do the substitution server side, however I was trying to clean up the data before it was returned.  I guess in this instance that doing it server side would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very interesting and very much tough to generate generic solution try this

this may help you

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100) = 'sample@gmail.com'

SELECT STUFF(STUFF(@STring,
                   CHARINDEX('@',@String)+2,
                   (CHARINDEX('.',@String, CHARINDEX('@',@String))-CHARINDEX('@',@String)-3),
                   REPLICATE('*',CHARINDEX('.',@String, CHARINDEX('@',@String))-CHARINDEX('@',@String)))
               ,2
               ,CHARINDEX('@',@String)-3
               ,REPLICATE('*',CHARINDEX('@',@String)-3))
```

OUTPUT will be

```
s****e@g******l.com
```

Similar way for thislong@emailaddress.com

OUTPUT will be

```
t******g@e*************s.com
```

Comment: That's fantastic!  I can wrap this into a neat little function. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: If you are going to wrap this into function then store `CHARINDEX('@',@String)` this into one variable  and use it this will improve performance as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100) = 'example@gmail.com'

SELECT  LEFT(@String, 1) + '*****@' 
+ REVERSE(LEFT(RIGHT(REVERSE(@String) , CHARINDEX('@', @String) +1), 1))
+ '******'
+ RIGHT(@String, 5)
```

> result will be
>       e******e@g***l.com

Answer (score 0):

You could also use regular expressions. Something like this (not completely finished):

```
select regexp_replace('test@email.com', '^(.?).*@(.?).*', '\1***@\2***')
from dual
```

Results in:

```
t***@e***
```

Could be a useful solution if you can only use SELECT statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.EmailObfuscate 
   (  @Email VARCHAR(255)
   )  RETURNS TABLE  AS RETURN
   (   
   SELECT      adr.email
             ,  LEFT (adr.email, 1) 
             +  REPLICATE ('*',  AtPos-3) 
             +  SUBSTRING (adr.Email, AtPos-1, 3) 
             +  REPLICATE ('*', Length-DotPos - AtPos - 2)
             +  SUBSTRING (adr.Email, Length - DotPos, 10)  AS hide
    FROM        ( VALUES ( @Email) ) AS ADR (EMail)     
    CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    CHARINDEX ('@', adr.Email)
                         ,  CHARINDEX ('.', REVERSE(Adr.Email))
                         ,  LEN (Adr.Email)
                ) positions (  AtPos
                            ,  dotpos
                            ,  Length
                            ) 
   );
GO
-- Calling
SELECT         Emails.* 
FROM         ( Values (  'this.long@emailaddress.com')
                   ,  (  'test@email.com'            )
                   ,  (  'sample@gmail.com'          )
                   ,  (  'test@gmx.de'               )
             ) AS     adr (email)
CROSS APPLY    dbo.EmailObfuscate (Adr.Email) AS Emails
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT 
   -- Email here is the name of the selected Column from your Table
   --Display the First Character
   SUBSTRING(Email,1,1)+
   --Replace selected Number of * 
   REPLICATE('*',10)+
   --Display the One Character before @ along with @ & One Character after @
   SUBSTRING(Email,CHARINDEX('@',Email)-1,3)+
   --Replace selected Number of * 
   REPLICATE('*',10)+
   --Display. Character along with the rest selected Number of Characters
   SUBSTRING(Email,CHARINDEX('.',Email)-1, LEN(Email) - 
   CHARINDEX('.',Email)+12) 
   --NameEmail is the Table Name      
   FROM NameEmail
```

> Result is:
>
> > j**********l@a**********a.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

I've found this answer, but was searching for PostgreSQL version (and have not found it)

So I've made my own for PGSQL

```sql
SELECT
    -- Email here is the name of the selected Column from your Table
    --Display the First Character
    SUBSTRING('g40gj30m@my-email.co.uk', 1, 1) ||
        --Replace selected Number of *
    REPEAT('*', 10) ||
        --Display the One Character before @ along with @ & One Character after @
    SUBSTRING('g40gj30m@my-email.co.uk', strpos('g40gj30m@my-email.co.uk', '@') - 1, 3) ||
        --Replace selected Number of *
    REPEAT('*', 10) ||
        --Display. Character along with the rest selected Number of Characters
    SUBSTRING(
            'g40gj30m@my-email.co.uk',
            strpos('g40gj30m@my-email.co.uk', '.') - 1,
            length('g40gj30m@my-email.co.uk') - strpos('g40gj30m@my-email.co.uk', '.') + 12
        );
```

the result will be

```sql
            ?column?             
---------------------------------
 g**********m@m**********l.co.uk
(1 row)
```