# SQL Server Query Output with sql scenario replace values with 'x'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one col in my table like:

```
COL
Kiyara@ymail.com
Akira@zmail.com
```

I want my output something like this:

```
COL
Kxxxxx@ymail.com
Axxxx@zmail.com
```

`iyara` replaced with 5x's(xxxxx) and 'kira' with 4x's(xxxx)

Comment: Did you try anything yet!

Comment: @Tanner Yes I have tried,but I'm able to get output like Kx@ymail.com,only single 'x', but I want 'x' value to be replicated according to the length of characters which are getting replaced.

Comment: SELECT STUFF(mailid,2,CHARINDEX('@',mailid)-2,REPLICATE('x', LEN(CHARINDEX('@',mailid)-2))) as mailid FROM  #TT-->mailId is column in #TT table

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38499321/hide-characters-in-email-address-using-an-sql-query

Comment: @Tanner It doesn't seem to be an _exact_ duplicate of that link, though maybe the OP could piece it together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's probably a better way to do it that this, but this achieves what you're after:

```
DECLARE @email NVARCHAR(50) = 'Kiyara@ymail.com';

SELECT  LEFT(@email, 1) + REPLICATE('X',
                                    LEN(SUBSTRING(@email, 2,
                                                  CHARINDEX('@', @email) - 1)))
        + SUBSTRING(@email, CHARINDEX('@', @email), LEN(@email));

-- Result: KXXXXXX@ymail.com
```

This uses the <kbd>[REPLICATE()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383.aspx)</kbd> method, which according to the docs online starts with SQL Server 2008.

> **REPLICATE (Transact-SQL)**
>
> Repeats a string value a specified number of times.
>
> `REPLICATE ( string_expression ,integer_expression )`

Comment: Thank You! It is giving output as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT LEFT(col, 1) + RIGHT('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', CHARINDEX('@', col) - 2) +
       SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('@', col), LEN(col) - CHARINDEX('@', col) + 1);
```

**Explanation:**

Take `Kiyara@ymail.com` as an example, and each piece of my query is shown here.

```
K           LEFT(col, 1)
xxxxx       RIGHT('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', CHARINDEX('@', col) - 2)
@ymail.com  SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('@', col), LEN(col) - CHARINDEX('@', col) + 1)
```

Note that you can replace the call to `RIGHT()` with a string of `x`'s long enough to match your longest expected email name.

Answer (score 0):

Try it's

```
select substring('Akira@zmail.com',1,1) + REPLICATE('x',charindex('@','Akira@zmail.com')) + SUBSTRING('Akira@zmail.com',charindex('@','Akira@zmail.com'),200)
```

Change the email by column or whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

```
 declare @n nvarchar(max)
 set @n='Kiyara@ymail.com'
 select concat(substring(@n,1,1),replicate('X',len( substring(@n,2,charindex('@',@n,1)-2))),SUBSTRING(@n,charindex('@',@n),200))
```

In this with the help o substring you have found first letter ans then rest of he letter til @ i.e iyara is searched using charindex ans substring,which will be converted into 'x' using replicate function and then rest id printed.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.